# import ``,ESLint: Cannot read property 'range' of null Occurred while linting

Tags: eslint

The error is because of this line of code

```
item.component = () => import(`@/views/${_component}`)
```

If I modify `.eslintrc.js`, it works

```
'indent' : "off",
'template-curly-spacing' : "off",
```

But this way, eslint won't help me format the code

when I run the following code, He can't work, but eslint has no errors:

```
item.component = () => import(`@/views/` + _component)
```

```
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
"eslint": "5.15.3",
```

node -v:   v12.9.1

eslint -v:  v6.8.0

vscode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting your eslint **indent rule** to contain: **ignoredNodes** for template literals. My `eslintrc.js` has the following:

```
rules: {
  indent: [2, "tab", { 
    ignoredNodes: ["TemplateLiteral"] 
  }],
  ... etc ...
}
```

That will ignore extended [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

If the above doesn't work, try deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` then re-install with `npm i` or `yarn`. This will restore your packages and reset downline versions.

Comment: This worked for me with Vue. After adjusting my ESLint settings, it would no longer allow me to `import Vue from 'vue'`. This fixed that.

Comment: Do you mean to try deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, NOT `package.json`?

Comment: not package.json you will all the package references.it's crucial. @ToddHale